# What is the difference between drupal (add container) and (add forum)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal, I can surf so many blogs i cant get clear idea about (add container) and (add forum) ?
any one explain.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why we use add container in Drupal Forum.

Answer (score 0):

Containers: can "contain" only other containers or forums, but not directly "threads" (or "discussions" or "topics")

Forums: contain threads but can also contain other forums (but not containers).